# flot points not inline with date and dates wrong?

Tags: php, mysql, flot

my charts seem to be all over the place right now..

im trying to plot a flot graph with data gathered from my database and failing hard...

here is my code;

```
<?php   
//session_start();

//include('Includes/auth.php');
//require_once('header.php');
include('Includes/connect.php');

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="cs" lang="cs">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf8"/>
<title>Index</title>
<script src="Includes/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="Includes/jquery.flot.js"></script>
<script src="Includes/jquery.flot.time.js"></script>

</head>
<?php
// Main query to pull data from 'tests' table
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `tests` WHERE member_id = '1'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("no query");

//  Dataset1
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
    $dataset1[] = array ( strtotime( $row['date'] ) * 1000, sprintf( "%.3f", $row['test1'] ) );
    }
?>

<div id="chart1" style="width:600px;height:400px;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    //Chart1
    var chart1Options = {
    xaxis: {
        mode: "time",
        timeformat: "%Y-%m-%d",
        axisLabel: 'Date' 
    },
      series: {
        lines: { show: true },
        color: "#fff",
        points: { show: true }
      },
       valueLabels: { show: true },
        grid: {
          backgroundColor: { colors: ["#4ca8fa", "#2887da"] },
          bordercolor: "#fff",
          borderwidth: "60",
          hoverable: true //IMPORTANT!
    }
    };

    var dataset1 = { label: "result", data: <?php echo json_encode($dataset1); ?>,};

    $.plot($("#chart1"), [ dataset1 ], chart1Options);
</script>
<?php echo json_encode($dataset1); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the data im trying to pull down and plot

[adata from mysql http://www.myreeftests.com/data.png](http://www.myreeftests.com/data.png)

and this is my graph using the above details:

http://www.myreeftests.com/graphs2.php

all over the place and  dates on xaxis are wrong??

any help please.

Thanks

Comment: The dates and values look fine to me; can you elaborate on what is wrong?

Comment: the graph doesnt look right and dates and dates on the axis dont match the dates in the database, nor do the points plot on the same lines as the dates on xaxis

Comment: im storing my date format as "Y-m-d" in the database without a timestamp? does this make a difference to converting to UNIX timestamp in milliseconds?

Answer (score 0):

i noticed one of my dates was almost 2 years less than the other which made the data throw out.